# Copying Certain Information From A Official Website

Tags: editing, citations, copyright, plagiarism

Hey Guys I was researching on a assignment I have to submit to my university. When i was about to copy certain information i went under the "Terms of Use" seeing if i could copy the said information and I saw this:

> The content and information displayed on the Sites are Awesome Company
>   and are collectively referred to as “Awesome Company Information”. The
>   downloading, reproduction, or re-transmission of this Information,
>   other than for non-commercial individual use, is strictly prohibited,
>   except to the extent permitted by travel agents for business-only
>   purposes (The Company Name & Text Has Been Changed To Avoid Misunderstanding)

Can someone please explain that if i copy any information or images from this site will i be a collaborator to plagiarism. I'll give out links for every text and image i may copy in my bibliography whence i am done with my assignment.
Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a little to what Lauren has said, make sure you understand the difference between copyright and plagiarism.

Copyright is the legal right to make a copy of the whole or parts of a work. Copyright automatically belongs to the person or organization that created the text, unless they sell it to someone else. Copyright holders can also licence some or all of their rights to others.

Copyright law says that people can copy parts of copyrighted works for certain purposes, such as academic criticism. This is known as the fair use doctrine.

In this case, the copyright holder has licensed further rights for individual non-commercial use.

Plagiarism is the act of representing someone else's work as your own. If you acknowledge the source of your content, then it is not plagiarism.

These are two independent concepts. If you copy more of a source than fair use or the licence granted by the owner allows, that is a copyright violation whether or not you cite your source.

If, in an academic paper, you copy text from a work that the owner has licensed for public use, but do not cite your source, that is still plagiarism even though it is not a copyright violation. (But note that when the owner of a copyrighted work grants you a license to use it, one of the terms of that licence may be that your must attribute your source. In that case, failure to attribute it would constitute both plagiarism and a copyright violation.)

Finally, note that most academic institutions expect you to do the work yourself. Copying from a source that is licensed for individual non-commercial use and citing that source means you have not violated copyright and you have not plagiarized, but you may still fail for not having actually done the work yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A university assignment probably falls under "non-commercial individual use." You aren't making money off the content.

Quote it and cite it, don't try to pass it off as your original work, and you should be fine. Quoting and citing is not plagiarism.